# CSS animation transform translateY also changing translateX, but is not specified in animation

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions, css-transforms

Here, I have a simple CSS file containing 2 animations.

```
.div
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.fade-in {
    animation-name: fade-in;
    animation-duration: .2s;
}

.fade-out {
    animation-name: fade-out;
    animation-duration: .2s;
}

@keyframes fade-out {
    0% {
        opacity: 100%;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0%;
        transform: translateY(-10px);
    }
}

@keyframes fade-in {
    0% {
        opacity: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-10px);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 100%;
    }
}
```

Why is it that even though I only specified translateY in the animation keyframes, it also manipulates the translateX in the transform property? And how can I make it so it only changes the Y value?

Comment: Could you add your HTML  JS code if you have it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overriding the `transform` peropty. Merge  `transform: translateX(-50%)` and  `transform: translateY(-10px);` by doing: `transform: translate(-50%, -10px);`

Do this:

```css
.div {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.fade-in {
  animation-name: fade-in;
  animation-duration: .2s;
}
.fade-out {
  animation-name: fade-out;
  animation-duration: .2s;
}
@keyframes fade-out {
  0% {
    opacity: 100%;
  }
  
  100% {
    opacity: 0%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -10px); /* NEW */
  }
}
@keyframes fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -10px); /* NEW */
  }
  
  100% {
    opacity: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You override whole `transform` attribute - not just translate. If you want to keep your `translateX` value you have to include it in animation too.

```css
@keyframes fade-out {
    0% {
        opacity: 100%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0%;
        transform: translateY(-10px) translateX(-50%);
    }
}
```